# Why Will Jquery Countdown Timer Not Accept PHP Date?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am using the Jquery "Final Countdown" Timer (found here: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) but I am modifying it to countdown from a date which is specified from a php var, like so:

PHP:

```
$gametimestamp = date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($gametimestamp));
```

Javascript:

```
var plustime = new Date(<?php echo $gametimestamp; ?>);
plustime.setSeconds(plustime.getSeconds() + 30);

  $("#timerinsert")
  .countdown(plustime, function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%M:%S')
    );
  });
```

If

```
 var plustime = new Date(<?php echo $gametimestamp; ?>);
```

Outputs like:

```
var plustime = new Date(2017/03/04 20:19:10);
```

Then why is the countdown timer not displaying? It DOES work if I just use

```
date();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add quotes when echoing strings to javascript

```
var plustime = new Date("<?php echo $gametimestamp; ?>");
```

And note that `new Date` accepts a certain format, preferably you'd echo seconds from epoch instead, and add three zeros

```
$gametimestamp = strtotime($gametimestamp); // Unix timestamp in seconds
```

and then

```
var plustime = new Date(<?php echo $gametimestamp; ?> * 1000); // in milliseconds
```